# What does によって mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, parsing

> 先輩と昼の街を歩く。
>   **いつもなら見向きもせずに通りすぎるような店によって**、二人してああでもないこうでもないと意見を合わせるだけの午前中。
>   結局なに一つとして買った物はなかったけど、そんなやりとりが時間を忘れるほど楽しかった。

I walk through the city with senpai during the day.
Usually, without even taking a look because we passed by the stores, we shared our opinions and passed time until midday.
At the end, we bought nothing but by doing that we had fun as if we forgot about time.

I do not understand that bold part.
によって=By, because of

But what is its role there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here this is に寄って, which just means "to stop by".  So

> いつもなら見向きもせずに通りすぎるような店によって　→　stopping by the kind of stores you'd normally pass by without even noticing (them)

Comment: Oh yeah, it makes perfect sense.