# コンビニによって帰ります - what does the "よって帰ります" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, verbs

My Sensei has said it means "popping in" to the shop. But I'm stuck on the "よって" part in particular. What verb is this? Is it an adverb instead?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but it's left me a little confused...

Comment: It should be the same よって (寄って) as in here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47249/translating-a-sentence-containing-%e3%81%ab%e3%82%88%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29757/what-does-%e3%81%ab%e3%82%88%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6-mean-in-this-sentence

Comment: So annoyed I didn't see that! Sorry for the dupe...